# Various ways to run angular 6 with web API project

Tags: angular6, asp.net-web-api2

We know that `ng serve` command used to run the app.

Also, we would like to know what all other ways to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

`ng serve` command is used in the development process to check parallel the result. Whatever in the `html` written can be reflected in the browser.